# Regarding tutorials on GWT

Tags: gwt

I am working on a new project , in which the GUI part is built on top of GWT(Google window toolkit),as I have to make few changes in GUI part , Please advise me some viedeo tutorials for GUI , although I am going through http://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/google-app-engine-hello-world-example-using-eclipse/
but please advise some best tutorials specially the viedeo one.Thanks in advance

also please advise google web toolkit and google app engine are they two different independent things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can start with `tutorial` of [helloworld.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0MjQg9Mssqw).

And then have a look at [Architecture building with GWT](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AapyOMOoQNM)

Finally with [Remote procedure calls](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hd5vnHNylB8) (`hitting backend`).

And finally your second Question [GWT with App engine](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M5x6E6ze1x8&playnext=1&list=PL254DA9E1D5FE58E3&feature=results_main)

And I'm suggesting to have a look at [GWT showcase](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCheckBox) and as well as code samples.

And the best GWT examples site [roughian](http://examples.roughian.com/#Home)

Comment: Another 8 videos about GWT, first: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTJ4w-J81oE

Comment: @FFire Ohoho..Really nice series for beginners :)